# How do I advance time in localnet?

Tags: anchor, epoch

I want to test a contract that does some staking stuff, so many of the instructions need to be conducted across epochs to properly test them. Obviously its not feasible to wait like 4 days for each test. So how do I advance time in my localnet so that the epoch passes between instruction calls?

Im using anchor and trdelnik if that matters

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the solana-program-test crate and then you can modify the clock sysvar and make it wrap to a specific slot.

In typescript, that's not really possible, you can bootstrap your validator to start at a specific slot.